# Rys Quadrature method for integrating over Gaussian basis functions: 1D integral recursion relation

Tags: hartree-fock, integrals, algorithms

I'm trying to implement the Rys Quadrature method for integrations of Gaussians, from scratch. I'm using [this](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/jcc.540110809) paper as a reference.

So, how does the overall recursion relation for evaluating 1D integrals (18) look like in the code? Python or C/C++ or anything similar that you can use would be fine.

[image]

As I see it, the recursive relation starts from calling the function calculating (18) which calls itself with different arguments until arguments equal 0. In this case, (11) is calculated. Which means I need nested if-else conditions, but what would they be like? The formulae (15) and (16) confuse me a lot, because they both correspond to *j* = 0, *l* = 0. And, also, what do *n* and *m* mean in the authors' notation?

In the text (15) and (16) are both referenced as Ix(ix + jx, 0, kx + lx, 0) which doesn't make any sense to me:

[image]

Comment: Well 11 gives you the initial value. Then 15 tells you how to step up in index 1 and 16 how to step up in index 3. Once you have I(*,0,*,0 )those you can use 17 to step up in index 2, and once you have I(*, *, *, 0) you can use 18 to step up in index 4. Unfortunately my institution doesn't pay for the journal so a little reluctant to say more without seeing the whole paper. (I'm assuming "o" in 15 is a typo/mis-scan for "0")

Comment: BTW why are you doing this, for your own education? If not there are a number of libraries out there which are free and implement these integrals (and more).

Comment: So there are for loops then? 
https://sci-hub.se/10.1002/jcc.540110809
I want to implement my absolutely own one which I would understand. Then I would do hardware-specific optimizations and make features like QFMM. It's often much harder to understand someone else's code than writing your own. Especially if you're giving me libint as an example.

Comment: Iteration or recursion, ultimately they're equivalent so your choice. If that is a link to the paper I can't read it - possibly a good thing legally.

Comment: Yes, it's a link to the paper.

Comment: Just to clarify, the Sci-Hub link doesn't work for me either, but the URL indicates that it's the same paper as the one (not from Sci-Hub) originally linked in the question. This confusion could have been avoided if Dmitry didn't just post a URL in that comment, without explaining that it's the same paper as the one linked in the question already. Also, Dmitry, have you figured out how to program this now? Are you still working on this code? The question can be re-opened if you ping me in a comment.